# What is the best way to detect that the identity server session has expired?

Tags: session, identityserver4

We have been using the checksession iframe but have been having issues with it detecting a session that has timed out due to inactivity. In our troubleshooting we've determined that idsrv4 has created a cookie called "idsrv.session" that the iframe polls. However, because of the cookie has no expiry date (session cookie), even after 30 minutes (our session length), the iframe still responds with "unchanged". We were attempting to set an expiry on this cookie but it seemed like the wrong approach. Any ideas?

Comment: Please include your code

Answer (score 1):

From http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html:

> 4.2.  OP iframe
>
> The OP browser state is typically going to be stored in a cookie or HTML5 local storage. It is origin bound to the Authorization Server. It captures meaningful events such as logins, logouts, change of user, change of authentication status for Clients being used by the End-User, etc. Thus, the OP SHOULD update the value of the browser state in response to such meaningful events. As a result, the next call to check_session() after such an event will return the value changed. It is RECOMMENDED that the OP not update the browser state too frequently in the absence of meaningful events so as to spare excessive network traffic at the Client in response to spurious changed events.

or more specifically

> change of authentication status

Are you coming from Identity Server 3? In 3 this cookie had an expiration date. It was removed in 4 because the spec didn't call for it:

> In IdSvr4 the entire UI for login will be the responsibility of the developer (you) and not the framework (us). So you can issue your own persistent cookie if you want.

(from https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/193)

Brock Allen (Identity Server author) mentions that you can create your own cookie middleware to have additional control over your cookies:

> The short answer as Dom said is to setup your own cookie middleware and let us know about it via this property: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/dev/src/IdentityServer4/Configuration/DependencyInjection/Options/AuthenticationOptions.cs#L21

(from https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/662)

For this particular cookie you may need to implement the IUserSession interface (previously, ISessionIdService) and register it through DI.

Comment: Thanks lots of good info here! I guess my main concern is: am I using the right approach using the iframe polling? Is it common for others to set expiry dates on these cookies? We have pretty tight identity server sessions which likely isn't a common scenario.